# Reading QR code with kraken and pyzbar from noisy/blurry images

Tags: python, qr-code, zbar

I have several photos with QR codes. I am trying to read them using kraken and Pyzbar, but some QR codes cannot be read.

Here is my code:

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, ZBarSymbol

from os.path import isfile, join

from kraken import binarization
from PIL import Image
from os.path import isfile, join

onlyfiles = [('Images/' + f) for f in os.listdir('Images/') if isfile(join('Images/', f))]
onlyfiles.remove('Images/Thumbs.db');
rand.shuffle(onlyfiles)

decoded = 0;
texts = [];

i = 1;
for file in onlyfiles:
    print(i, file, end=' ')

    im = Image.open(file);
    bw_im = binarization.nlbin(im);
    decodeQR = decode(bw_im);

    if len(decodeQR) == 0:
        print("NO");
    else:
        decoded += 1;
        print('YES');
        texts.append(decodeQR[0].data);

    i+=1;

print("Decoded: " + str(decoded) + '/' + str(len(onlyfiles)));
print(texts);
```

and here is the example of file that is not being read with code, but can be readed by my phone:
[image]

What I need to do?

P.S. Sorry for bad english!

Comment: that picture (QR code) is incredibly noisy and blurry. don't expect results from that picture.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i know, but i can read it with my phone camera without any problem

Comment: and so can I, which kinda surprises me. you'll probably need to find a good threshold level (or the library needs to do it)... I notice that you use `kraken` for that. look at the output. show it here (edit your question). -- this is basic debugging, looking into the steps and the intermediate results. you should have done that. -- I know tagging `OpenCV` summons spirits that rip through any problem, but if you don't use OpenCV, the tag is inappropriate.